# Are there software/apps that can communicate with WhatsApp? (Other than WhatsApp itself)

Tags: android, phone, whatsapp

I read in a top"N"-type messengers app list that Wire could communicate with WhatsApp and allowed voice calls (though it wasn't said what version of Wire they were talking about and if it allowed actual calls to WhatsApp or only text messages or such). However, I just installed personnal version of Wire and I do not find any other information or setting about this.

So are there actually messengers that can communicate with WhatsApp? (Other than WhatsApp) Or was this a myth?

Characteristics I'm looking for:

- An Android app version
- Does not require a phone number
- Does not required access to phone contacts
- Allows voice calls
- A browser version is a nice to have
- Open source is a plus (nice to have, not must have)
- Free or very low budget
- Can communicate with WhatsApp (if this exists at all)

---

Edit: I tried contacting Wire directly but they have some kind of automated reply that says that they do not reply to the tickets of their "Personnal" users... At some point I may look if there is some Wire community/forum somewhere...

Comment: The second point seems impossible, as Whatsapp bases its accounts on phone numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Not impossible... I could imagine various workarounds to this. But do I think it is likely that they were implemented anywhere? Well, not really.